# How to execute a function completely and then move forward AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a way to completely execute a function and then move forward for whatever operations are needed.

```
var responseOutput = [];
function myFunction(){
    //DO SOMETHING
    Service.callDownStreamService()
    .then (function (response) {
       responseOutput.push(response.object);
    }).catch (function (error) {
       //DO SOMETHING
    });

    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

I need to execute my Service.callDownStreamService separately and only after executing it, I need to move further.
I am not able to synchronise it completely and the responseObject results in irregular format of data.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Make `myFunction` an `async` function and add `await` before `Service.callDownStreamService` call.

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx, Can you please elaborate? I am new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your async method call around a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Advanced_Example) as follows:

```js
var responseOutput = [];

function myFunction() {
  //DO A THING
  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Service.callDownStreamService()
      .then(function(response) {
        responseOutput.push(response.object);
        resolve(); //DO ANOTHER THING ON SUCCESS
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        reject(); //DO A THING WHEN FAILED
      });
  });

  promise.then(function() {
      //DO ANOTHER THING ON SUCCESS
    })
    .catch(function() {
      //DO A THING WHEN FAILED
    });
}
```